# Selenium throws error while trying to add extension - "Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary" and "Cannot locate node containing extension id"

Tags: selenium

I am trying to get Selenium to install an extension while testing. I am using the latest standalone JAR (`selenium-server-standalone-2.26.0.jar`) and Firefox 17 to run my tests. The program works perfectly when I am not trying to add the extension.

I have verified multiple times that the extension file that I am trying to use exists and can be accessed by the program and does in fact contain a valid install.rdf because I used it to manually install the extension in my default Firefox profile.

My code is :

```
FirefoxProfile fp=new FirefoxProfile();
File ext=new File("myext-2.17.xpi");
        try {
            fp.addExtension(ext);
            fp.setPreference("extensions.myext.version", "myext-2.17");
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
WebDriver wd=new FirefoxDriver(fp);
```

The full Stack Trace is as follows :

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-2" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follows: 
null
Build info: version: '2.26.0', revision: '18041', time: '2012-11-01 19:33:38'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_02'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:243)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:109)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:189)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:178)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
    at TrafficGenerator.BrowserWindow.run(BrowserWindow.java:80)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot locate node containing extension id: C:\Users\Vivek\AppData\Local\Temp\unzip3924903411706376479stream\install.rdf
Build info: version: '2.26.0', revision: '18041', time: '2012-11-01 19:33:38'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_02'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
Build info: version: '2.26.0', revision: '18041', time: '2012-11-01 19:33:38'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_02'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.FileExtension.readIdFromInstallRdf(FileExtension.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.FileExtension.writeTo(FileExtension.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.installExtensions(FirefoxProfile.java:465)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.layoutOnDisk(FirefoxProfile.java:443)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:77)
    ... 10 more
```

The error exists on using FF16 and FF9 too.
Any ideas on what could be the cause of the error and how I could fix it?

Comment: What happens if you downgrade your version of Firefox to 16?

Comment: @Arran - the same issue occurs on FF 16 as well as FF 9.

Comment: Debug iteratively. Comment out all but the top line and see if that fails. Then continue until it does. The profile may not be a legitimate object to pass to the Driver.

Comment: @Shawn - already tried that. The profile is a valid object.

Answer (score -1):

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot locate node containing extension id: C:\Users\Vivek\AppData\Local\Temp\unzip3924903411706376479stream\install.rdf
```

Looks like your extension is missing a required "extension id" field in the RDF description.

You might try to start Firefox without your extension and try to install your extension in a running Firefox without selenium.

Comment: In the question, I have already mentioned that the extension installs properly when doing it manually. The extension id field exists in the install.rdf file.

Comment: Ah sorry didn't noticed, have you tried to use the absolute path to the xpi? If you just use the name it might not work, as your applications working directory might not be the directory you think, especially when you run the test from an IDE like Eclipse.

But there might be an ID missing on something else, you might debug the corresponding selenium code: http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-firefox-driver/2.0a6/selenium-firefox-driver-2.0a6-sources.jar!/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/internal/FileExtension.java?format=ok

Comment: Yes, tried the absolute path too. I have mentioned in the question that the program can access the file and I have verified that it exists through the program itself.