# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: {user}\AppData\Local\Temp\stream\install.rdf (The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run selenium in firefox 33. (downgraded as per some posts here)

I zipped and created the xpi file from the extensions folder from this location:

```
C:\Users\kchait001c\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\cyn5o9lv.default\extensions
```

I am still getting this error

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Temp\unzip3974297545324944844stream\install.rdf (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

not sure why it is referencing to Temp folder. 
I have my install.rdf file in

```
C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\cyn5o9lv.default\extensions\{9EB34849-81D3-4841-939D-666D522B889A}\install.rdf
```

I tried the following:
http://codedmi.com/questions/4960112/cannot-find-firefox-binary-in-path-make-sure-firefox-is-installed-error-in-remo

This is the exact problem along with the error log in this post. this post doesnt give me a solution:
[Selenium throws error while trying to add extension - "Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary" and "Cannot locate node containing extension id"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722217/selenium-throws-error-while-trying-to-add-extension-failed-to-connect-to-bina)

please suggest a solution.

attaching error log from my machine:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at fit.FixtureLoader.loadFixtureClass(FixtureLoader.java:67)
at fit.FixtureLoader.instantiateFixture(FixtureLoader.java:60)
at fit.FixtureLoader.instantiateFirstValidFixtureClass(FixtureLoader.java:84)
at fit.FixtureLoader.disgraceThenLoad(FixtureLoader.java:44)
at fit.Fixture.loadFixture(Fixture.java:142)
at fit.Fixture.getLinkedFixtureWithArgs(Fixture.java:134)
at fit.Fixture.interpretFollowingTables(Fixture.java:120)
at fit.Fixture.interpretTables(Fixture.java:107)
at fit.Fixture.doTables(Fixture.java:81)
at fit.FitServer.process(FitServer.java:81)
at fit.FitServer.run(FitServer.java:56)
at fit.FitServer.main(FitServer.java:41)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to     binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox_binary.exe) on port 7055; process output follows: 
null
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
System info: host: 'HQSWL-C008398', ip: '172.24.117.170', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:138)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:117)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
at com.comcast.app.seleniumui.slingbox.SlingBoxUiLoginForFirefox.getBrowserCode(SlingBoxUiLoginForFirefox.java:46)
at com.comcast.app.seleniumui.slingbox.SlingBoxUiLoginForFirefox.(SlingBoxUiLoginForFirefox.java:31)
... 14 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Temp\unzip3974297545324944844stream\install.rdf (The system cannot find the file specified)
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
System info: host: 'HQSWL-C008398', ip: '172.24.117.170', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.FileExtension.readIdFromInstallRdf(FileExtension.java:142)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.FileExtension.writeTo(FileExtension.java:61)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.installExtensions(FirefoxProfile.java:443)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.layoutOnDisk(FirefoxProfile.java:421)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:95)
... 21 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:      C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Temp\unzip3974297545324944844stream\install.rdf (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:93)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:205)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.FileExtension.readIdFromInstallRdf(FileExtension.java:98)
... 25 more
```

Comment: I figured it out for this issue, I have zipped the extensions folder instead of extensions/{324SJGDF-3FDG-E34SD-SDFG3FG} which has the install.rdf file.